# Jasmine testing Backbone, Scoping trouble

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I really got an annoying error when writing jasmine tests for one of my current backbone collections and I think it's not the way I write the test instead of doing something wrong in my javascript and jasmine wants to tell me that. But I can't find a solution.

I got the following simplified code which will lead us to the problem

```
class Stuff extends Backbone.Collection
    search: (str) ->
        @trigger('search', @_filter(@_convertStrToArray(str)))

    _convertStrToArray: (str) ->
        str.toLowerCase().split()

    _filter: (str_array) ->
        @filter (stuff) ->
            for _sub in str_array
                ... do something here
```

I would like to test with jasmine, if the @_convertStrToArray method has been called on executing @search. I got the following test (@stuff has been successfully created in a beforeEach statement!)

```
...
it "should call _convertStrToArray", ->
    spyOn(@stuff, '_convertStrToArray')
    @stuff.search('cool stuff')
    expect(@stuff._convertStrToArray).toHaveBeenCalled()
...
```

I am getting the following error in my jasmine test now..

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

By tracking down the stacktrace I found out that the error comes from the following line:

```
for _sub in str_array
```

Obviously there is a scoping problem here I am not able to solve. The **@filter** method in the **_filter** method comes from Backbone. The script works absolutely fine, I am just having trouble with the test.

**My question: How can I correctly gain access on the str_array variable in the @filter call?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your spy. The `for _sub in str_array` is using an index / length check to iterate, but the spied on `_convertStrToArray` doesn't return any value.

You need to add `.andCallThrough()` to the end of your spy definition:

`spyOn(@stuff, '_convertStrToArray').andCallThrough()`

This will spy on the method, but still call the actual method and it's return value so that your code won't fail when it tries to use the result.

Comment: Thanks for your great help, that was it!